# Reloading data makes data stack and duplicates with .append - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a table that is dynamically fed with ajax and using Jquery to append the data to my table. So far this is working fine but when I try to reload the data it just stacks up the data.

Below is the function I have going so far and its working great when initially loading the page.

```
loadIncidents: function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.basePath() + '/GDI_PROD_Incidents?$filter=ÉtatValue%20ne%20%27Fermé%27&$orderby=PrioritéValue desc',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data.d.results, function (index, incident) {

            $('#example').append(
            "<tr>" +
            "<td> <button class='edit_button btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xs' name ='btnSubmit' type='button' value='Edit' data-ID='"+incident.ID+"'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit' data-original-title='' title=''></i></button></td>" +
            "<td>" + incident.Incident + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + incident.PrioritéValue + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + incident.Composante + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + incident.Description + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + incident.DateDeDébut + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + incident.DateDeFin + "</td>" +
            "</tr>");                   

            })
        }
    });
},
```

I then created this refresh function basically to refresh the data after certain actions are performed. It seems to be working but instead of reloading my table with the updated list of records it just stacks up my data.

```
// Refreshes the search result.
refreshInicidents: function () {
    this.loadIncidents();
},
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="example">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Action</th>
                        <th>Incident</th>
                        <th>Priorité</th>
                        <th>Composante</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Date de début</th>
                        <th>Date de fin</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

I was looking into the Jquery documentation and tried .html but that just seems to break the table. Looking for some advice on the best way to go about this. Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to empty the parent HTML element, in this case likely the `<tbody>`.

In your code, your success function could first do this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('tbody').empty();
    ...
```

This will first clear any data that might already be present, then will immediately continue on with your other code and append the new data in place!

[.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Comment: I did as you suggested and worked out great. Thanks Charles.